# What is the difference between passing classes as generic types or types?

Tags: swift, generics

In the Swift documentation, I came across a section which was saying that I can write type constraints like a method or a protocol. However, what I didn't understand were the benefits of writing this way. Why don't simply pass the class (or protocol) itself?

Documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

Let me explain with an example.

```
import Foundation

class A {
    init(val: String) {
        self.val = val
    }
    let val: String
}

func someFunction<T: A>(someT: T) {
    print(someT.val)
}

func someFunction2(someT: A) {
    print(someT.val)
}

// method 1
someFunction(someT: A(val: "asdasd"))
// method 2
someFunction2(someT: A(val: "asdasd"))
```

In the snippet below, what is the difference between method 1 and method 2?

Comment: Not sure if this is the only reason, but with `someFunction<T: A>(someT: T)` you could introduce a generic constrain, e.g. `where T: CustomStringConvertable`

Comment: For me the advantage of generics are more obvious with a class/struct or a protocol with an associated type than with a single function. Specially like in this example when you have this constraint on T. _Edit: and as I wrote that @NewDev came up with a good reason :)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your overly simplified example, there's not much difference.

However, as soon as your type constraints become more complex, the only way to achieve the desired interface is via generics.

A great example if when you want a function to take an input argument whose type is a protocol with an associated type, such as SwiftUI's `View`.

If you tried to use `View` as the input argument type, you'd get a compile time error

```
func modifyView(_ view: View) {

}
```

> Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

However, as soon as you make `view` generic with a type constraint on `View`, the code compiles.

```
func modifyView<V: View>(_ view: V) {

}
```

You don't have to look at custom functions, the standard library is full of generic functions as well. `JSONDecoder.decode` showcases another common use case for generics, when you want your function to return a specific type based on some input arguments. This enables the developer to only write the function 1x, but make it work on lots of different types, while keeping type safety.

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T
```